# Business Event Handler not working in openbravo

Tags: java, postgresql-8.4, openbravo

I have created a manual window in openbravo. This manual window inserts records in table A.
To this table their is business event handler which gets activated when row is added, updated or deleted to the table A and if any change is their, this event inserts,updates or deletes in another table B.Now the problem is that whenever i changed the rows(that is add a new row,update or delete it ) manually in ERP then the event is working , But when did through process this event is not getting called.

Can anybody suggest what should i do?

Comment: First try to add and save lines manually and check if business event is working properly? then you can trigger it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business entity events only **work** when accessing the database through the **data access layer** (DAL), so they do not work for classic windows or direct jdbc calls!.

You may be using some Native SQL Queries(XSQL) or JDBC calls in the process , that is the reason It is working through UI but not java process execution.

[click here for more informaiton](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_implement_a_business_event_handler#Introduction)